# Can I specify a stylesheet for HTML5 apps to use on the iPhone when running in offline/standalone mode?

Tags: iphone, html, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm building an HTML5/JavaScript app that runs on the iPhone in offline mode.

I know I can selectively run JavaScript by inspecting the `window.navigator.standalone` property - is there some equivalent switch/selector for CSS? The extra screen space that's available when running locally means I'd like to use different CSS for running as a web page vs. running as an offline app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no declarative, CSS-only way that I'm aware of (such as using a media-query).

One shortcut option might be to use the trick that people use on Android, which does not have an installable HTML5 option at all: scroll the URL bar out of view. See http://www.html5rocks.com/mobile/mobifying.html#toc-optimizations-scrolling

At least that way users get a "full-screen" appearance.  You may want to couple that with a `min-height` on the body or containing element to make sure it actually stretches far enough to scroll the URL bar out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cache manifest and provide a completely different CSS when viewing offline (under FALLBACK): http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/offline-applications-html5-appcache/